# Minimalistic Python extension module providing a function sorting a list using Python sorted()

Tags: c++, python-3.x, function, extension-modules

I am currently working on a C++ Python extension module and want to use in this module Pythons own standard library functions for performing operations on to the extension module passed objects.

Down to an simple example I would like to know how to call in C++ Pythons standard library function sorted() on the to the extension module function passed Python list object.

In other words the question is:

> How to express in C++ of an Python extension module an equivalent of following Python code:

```
def extModuleSortedFunction(sortableList):

   return sorted(sortableList)
```

?